# How to read a file and make records for each line

Tags: arrays, perl, function, hash, bioinformatics

Looking for help on writing a Perl program that takes an input file and performs manipulations based on follow-up commands. I'm a beginning Perl student so please don't get too advance in suggestions. The structure that I have so far is a main program and 4 subs.

I'm having trouble with two parts:

> 1. Writing the portion of the main segment that creates a unique record for each line from the input file (which is fixed width format). I think this should be done with substr but I don't know much more of how this should be structured. Unpack is beyond the scope of my learning so far.
> 2. One of the functions called in the main program is a "distance" sub which will calculate distance between atoms. I'm thinking this should be a For Loop inside a For loop. Any thoughts on what approach I should take?

The records should store an array of atom records (one record/atom per newline):

• The atom's serial number, 5 digits. (cols 7 - 11)

• The three-letter name of the amino acid to which it belongs (cols 18 - 20)

• The atom's three coordinates real number as decimal & Orthogonal Coordinates (x,y,z) (cols 31 - 54 )
For X in Angstroms cols. 31-38
For Y in Angstroms cols. 39-46
For Z in Angstroms cols. 47-54

• The atom's one- or two-letter element name (e.g. C, O, N, Na) (cols 77-78 )

sub Distance
    # take an array of atom records and return the max distance
    # between all pairs of atoms in that array. (cols 31-54)

Here is sample text from an input file.

```
# truncating for testing purposes. Actual data is aprox. 100 columns     
# and starts with ATOM or HETATM    
__DATA__   
ATOM   4743  CG  GLN A 704      19.896  32.017  54.717  1.00 66.44           C    
ATOM   4744  CD  GLN A 704      19.589  30.757  55.525  1.00 73.28           C    
ATOM   4745  OE1 GLN A 704      18.801  29.892  55.098  1.00 75.91           O
```

Here is what I have so far for the main and sub for make records. I hate to be lame but I don't have anything to show for the Distance sub yet so don't worry about giving code, any suggestions on how to approach would be very appreciated.

```
use warnings;
use strict; 

my @fields;
my @recs;

while ( <DATA> ) {
chomp;
@fields = split(/\s+/);
push @recs, makeRecord(@fields);
}

for (my $i = 0; $i < @recs; $i++) {
printRec( $recs[$i] );
}
my %command_table = (
  freq => \&freq,
  length => \&length,
  density => \&density,
  help => \&help, 
  quit => \&quit
);

print "Enter a command: ";
  while ( <STDIN> ) {
  chomp; 
  my @line = split( /\s+/);
  my $command = shift @line;
  if ($command !~ /^freq$|^density$|length|^help$|^quit$/ ) {
    print "Command must be: freq, length, density or quit\n";
  }
    else {
    $command_table{$command}->();
  }
print "Enter a command: ";
}

sub makeRecord 
# Read the entire line and make records from the lines that contain the 
# word ATOM or HETATM in the first column. Not sure how to do this:
{
 my %record = 
 (
 serialnumber => shift,
 aminoacid => shift,
 coordinates => shift,
 element  => [ @_ ]
 );
 return\%record;
 }
```

Comment: Why is `unpack` out of your scope of learning when you're making use of a dispatch table?

Comment: @Zaid My class just learned functions but we haven't learned Unpack.

Comment: The one caveat with using `unpack` is that you have to get the template right. You are given the start and end columns for each field you have to read. The `@` code jumps to the desired starting position, except it's zero-based, so to jump to column 7, for example, you can use `@6`, and then to jump to column 18, you can use `@17`. That way you don't have to count the spaces you are skipping.

Comment: The man page for `unpack` is at http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html.

Comment: @Narveson thanks. Unpack seems straightforward enough. Nonetheless, my professor has asked for us to wait until next semester before getting into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's Perl code available online for working with PDB files (which obviously you are doing). I'm not suggesting just using a module you downloaded and be done with it, as surely your instructor wouldn't approve, and you wouldn't learn that much ;)  But you could take a look at some of the code that's offered and try to see whether some bits there address your problem.

I did a quick bit of googling, I saw that there's ParsePDB.pm (for example). You can find the web page [here](http://comp.chem.nottingham.ac.uk/parsepdb/). I didn't have a look at the code or the functionality though, I'm just hoping there will be something in there that you may find helpful.

*EDIT 1*

Okay, it's 14 hours later now, and I felt like doing some coding, so as you have not yet accepted an answer I thought I could just ignore my own advice and draw up something (as you will notice I have copied Zaid's data structure)...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

sub makeRecord {
   my ($ser_num, $aa, $x, $y, $z, $element) = @_;
   # copying Zaid now as her/his structure looks very sensible!
   my $record = {
                  serial  => $ser_num,
                  aa      => $aa,
                  element => $element,
                  xyz     => [$x, $y, $z],
                };
   return $record;
}


my $file = shift @ARGV;
my @records; # will be an array of hash references

open FILE, "<$file" or die "$!";
while (<FILE>) {
   if (/^ATOM|^HETATM/) { # only get the structure data lines
      chomp; # not necessary here, but good practice I'd say

      my @fields = split; # by default 'split' splits on whitespace

      # now use an array slice to only pass the array elements
      # you're interested in (using the positional indices from @fields):
      push @records, makeRecord(@fields[1,3,6,7,8,11]);
   }
}
close FILE;
```

*EDIT 2*

Concerning the distance subroutine: the for loop inside the for loop should do the job, but this is the brute force way which might take quite a while (as you'd have to do (number_of_atoms)^2 calculations), depending on the size of your input molecule. For the purpose of your assignment the brute force approach is probably acceptable; in other cases you'd have to decide whether to favour ease of coding, or computational speed. If your instructor also wants you to keep the latter in mind, you could take a look at [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points) (I know you actually want the largest distance, and you're in 3D, not 2D...)

Ok, now I just hope that you managed to find some helpful bits and pieces in here :)

Answer (score 1):

Your records have a fixed-width format, so use `unpack` to break each record into the fields of interest.  Use the stated column positions of each field to construct a template for use with `unpack`.

```
my @field_specs = (
    {begin =>  7, end => 11, name => 'serialnumber'},
    {begin => 18, end => 20, name => 'aminoacid'},
    {begin => 31, end => 38, name => 'X'}, 
    {begin => 39, end => 46, name => 'Y'},
    {begin => 47, end => 54, name => 'Z'}, 
    {begin => 77, end => 78, name => 'element'},
);
my $unpack_template;    
my @col_names;
for my $spec (@field_specs) {
    my $offset = $spec->{begin} - 1;
    my $width  = $spec->{end} - $offset;
    $template .= "\@${offset}A$width";
    push @col_names, $spec->{name};
}
print "Ready to read @col_names\n using template $template ...\n";

# prints 
# Ready to read serialnumber aminoacid X Y Z element 
#  using template @6A5@17A3@30A8@38A8@46A8@76A2 ...

my @recs;
while ( <DATA> ) {                
    my %record;
    @record{@col_names} = unpack($unpack_template, $_);    
    push @recs, \%record;                
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is strange that [`unpack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) is out of scope when I can see use of a dispatch table. It would be silly to overlook using `unpack` if fixed-format files are being processed. There is nothing 'advanced' going on in the code below:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump 'dump';   # Use this if you want 'dump' function to work

my @records;
while ( my $record = <DATA> ) {

    next unless $record =~ /^ATOM|^HETATM/;  # Skip unwanted records

    # unpack minimizes the amount of work the code has to do ...
    # ... especially since you only want a small part of the file
    # 'x' tokens are ignored, 'A' tokens are read ...
    # The number following each token represents repetition count ...
    # ... so in this case the first 6 characters are ignored ...
    # ... and the next 5 are assigned to $serNo

    my ( $serNo, $aminoAcid, $xCoord, $yCoord, $zCoord )
        = unpack 'x6A5x6A3x10A10A10A10', $record;        # Get only what you want

    # Assign data to a hash reference

    my $recordStructure = {
                            serialnumber => $serNo,
                            aminoacid    => $aminoAcid,
                            coordinates  => [ $xCoord, $yCoord, $zCoord ],
                          };

    push @records, $recordStructure;  # Append current record
}

# 'dump' is really useful to view data structures. No need for PrintRec!!

dump @records;
```